# Serialize complex objetcs using mmap

Tags: c++

I would like to serialize a complex object into a binary file using mmap in C++. By complex object I mean an object that contains pointers (like a tree data structure).

The idea is to be able to load the object later from the file with mmap in that way :

```
my_structure obj = (my_structure)mmap(...)
```

without needing to reload all the data structure, for purposes of performance (because it is a huge data structure !).
All examples I found on the internet are very reductive (like how to put an int in a file ...) and I don't find anything about how to write the memory corresponding to an object that contains pointeurs ? How can we do that ?

Note : I'm on mac osx

Comment: First things first, don't persist pointers as they may be dangling after a reload.

Comment: @EricZ: i'm kind of guessing that is it exactly why he wants to use mmap, he might be feeling there is a way to obtain the same base address for a block of memory, which would make the pointer compatible out of the box when reloading.

Comment: Have you searched for "binary serialization c++" on google? check out the answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is one interesting way of doing it that i have seen but it's use is somewhat limited:

First you can't serialize pointers or any other non POD type. The way you can get serialize the structure with pointer reference is to have a special type that instead of keeping the pointer value keeps an offset from it's memory location:

example:

```
struct void_ptr
{
    int     offset;

    void * get ()
    {
        return ((char*)this) + offset;
    }
};

//or for generic type:

template <class T>
struct t_ptr
{
    int     offset;

    T * get ()
    {
        return (T*)(((char*)this) + offset);
    }
};
```

Second, you need to have a special serializer that will compute the offsets of all the members inside the class/structure

let's take an example , you want to serialize struct A:

```
struct A
{
    t_ptr<int>  pointer_to_int;//let's suppose it points to an array of 2 ints      
    int         my_value;
};
```

the total memory requirement for this structure is 16 bytes or 4 ints (one int for `my_value`, one for `pointer_to_int` offset, and 2 for the int array pointer to int points to)
The array that `pointer_to_int` points to needs to be located in memory right after A structure memory data and the offset of `int_ptr` should be sizeof(A) because

example:

```
int m[] = { 8, 1, 2, 3 };

A& a = *(A*)&m[0];

std::cout << a.my_value << std::endl;
std::cout << a.pointer_to_int.get()[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << a.pointer_to_int.get()[1] << std::endl;
```

**It's very important to know and handle the memory alignment when doing such a thing!!!**

Comment: this kind of direct "memory dump to reload" techniques, are used in games. The serializing tools do cross platform alignment of a prepared, pre-packed serialized structure that is ready to be read stupidly at runtime on the target platform, and the pointer fixed after reading; and there is no allocation to be done further than the original block of data. Completely optimal de-serialization, done at the speed of the media stream :) (or almost)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i'll will check that !

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is dangerous in C++. It's enough to have a pointer or reference as a member to fail, as you won't be able to restore those when deserializing. You won't be able to restore pointers directly since the addresses of data change between runs.

Most probably you'd want to check out the following pages:

- [Cap’n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/)
- [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/)
- [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

You will also probably need to restructure your program, such that for the serialized data you don't use pointers as members, as most libraries dictate a suitable serializable data structure for you: either their own generated classes or combinations of plain data and STL.

Depending on the nature of the data, you might want to split or chunk the data.